# gem install passengerすると失敗する

Tags: ruby

こちらのサイトを参考にpassengerを導入しようとしています
http://qiita.com/nametaketakewo/items/bb6294488ee30f5ef418

しかしgem install passengerをしようとすると以下のようなエラーがでてきてしまい、前に進めません

```
Fetching: rack-2.0.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing passenger:
rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
```

rubyのバージョンは以下の通りです

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [x86_64-linux]
```

OSはCentOS7を使っております。

エラーを読むと、rubyのバージョンを2.2.2以上にすればいいとのことですが、2.2.2に上げるとアプリが動かなくなるのでそれは避けたいです。

どうすればバージョン2.1.xでpassengerは使えますでしょうか。ご教授頂けますと幸いです

Answer (score 0, accepted):

検証できてませんが、passengerに同内容のissueがあったので試してみてください。

[rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2 · Issue #1710 · phusion/passenger](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1710)

rackのバージョンを2.2に依存しないものに固定することで対応できるようです。

```
gem install rack -v=1.6.4
gem install passenger -v=5.0.30 --conservative
```

まあRuby自体を更新できるのが手っ取り早い気はしますが……(2.1系もセキュリティサポート終了が近付いてますしね……)